# On Windows do I *have to* call WaitForSingleObject() after calling CreateProcess()?

Tags: c, linux, windows, operating-system

On Linux, I have to call `wait()` after `fork()` on the parent process, otherwise the child process will stay zombie after completion until the parent process completes.

**I wonder whether I must follow similar steps on Windows,**
i.e. whether I **must** call `WaitForSingleObject()` after calling `CreateProcess()`.

I know that Windows' `CreateProcess()` is different from Linux's `fork()` and it seems that 'zombie' is a UNIX/Linux concept that does not exist on Windows. But maybe I still must call `WaitForSingleObject()` to free some OS resources allocated for `CreateProcess()`, similar to the Linux case.

Comment: The more equivalent Windows C call would be `_beginthread()`. The `CreateProcess()` starts an independent process.

Comment: A new window process from `CreateProcess()` has its own life. The parent process can call `WaitForSingleObject()` if it want monitor the child life.

Comment: no, you must not wait

Comment: fork() also creates a separate process

Comment: @RbMm I suspect so, but how can I be sure? Do you have any reference?

Comment: @Alexander - i dont know which reference here need. but in indows process is independed from it parent. you can wait for it, if want, but must not.

Comment: @Alexander it depends on your use case. Let's say you start your favorite word processor using `CreateProcess`. If you want to wait until the user has closed the word processor (IOW the word processor process has ended), then you need to use `WaitForSingleObject`, if you don't want to wait, then don't use it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky In my use case I don't care. I.e. I receive everything from the child process via a pipe and I know that once I've received everything the child process is supposed to terminate. So I can either wait or proceed without waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CreateProcess` succeeds you must close the two handles in `PROCESS_INFORMATION` but you don't have to wait for the child process first, the handles can be closed at any point if you don't need them.

A open handle to a process will keep the process object alive in a zombie state after it has finished running.

Comment: thanks for the answer. For completeness, do you have any proof link or any justification why it's not needed on Windows, i.e. why it's only enough to close the handles?

Comment: @Alexander if `CreateProcess` __required __to use `WaitHandle` after, then it would be written in the documentation of `CreateProcess`.

Comment: I don't have any Microsoft documentation I can link to but the justification is that this is just how kernel handles work on Windows. You close them when you are done with them without caring about the state of the object. If you happened to close the last open handle, the kernel will then deal with the cleanup.